# How to set a timeout to stop execution of setInterval method; not on counter but after given time period

Tags: javascript, setinterval

If I want to execute the code on a given interval, I can use `setInterval()` function as below.
How to set a timeout to stop execution of setInterval method; not on counter but after given time period

```
let currentStatus = 'InProgress';
console.log(currentStatus);

if (currentStatus === 'InProgress') {
  let timerId = setInterval(async () => { 
    console.log('tick')
  }, 2000);
}
```

Just want to share a simple example for this, so posting this Q&A.

Comment: Maybe set it as community/wiki?

Comment: @downvoter, what's wrong with this question? do you care to explain? I just want to share a simple example for this, so posted the question and the answer.

Comment: Not me who down-voted,  but looking at your profile, you seem to ask a lot of questions, and then answer yourself, and then accept.  To me this seems like a deliberate way to up your rep.  Not sure if it against SO policy, but for me it seems to go against the spirit of SO.   And like @abiessu has kind of pointed out, SO is not a WIKI..

Comment: @KuldeepJain  Like I said wasn't me who down-voted, but just pointing out why somebody might have done so, you did say "do you care to explain?".  There are discussions on Meta about this, from what I can gather it's not something SO are against.   But it does seem to create mixed feelings,  so I suppose you just need to be prepared for potential down-voters.

Comment: Thanks @Keith, appreciate you responding. I understand your point.
What I wanted to point out is, probably this is the only question that I posted while knowing the answer. But all my other questions are the ones for which I was looking for a solution. And when I did not get any answer and I figured it out so I feel I must answer it. And since we cannot upvote our own Q&A so there is no reason anyone would do it to up the rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `setTimeout()` function with `clearInterval()` to set the timeout, after which the execution of the code as specified by *TimerHandler* in *setInterval* will stop.

```
let currentStatus = 'InProgress';
console.log(currentStatus);

if (currentStatus === 'InProgress') {
  let timerId = setInterval(async () => { 
    console.log('tick')
  }, 2000);

  // after 10 seconds stop
  setTimeout(() => { clearInterval(timerId); console.log('stop'); }, 10000);
  console.log('done');
}
```

See this link for details: https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval